# How to register trigger in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-triggers

I have trigger and procedure. I want to be sure that string saved to database will have no '-' characters.

After executing

```
UPDATE interesant SET interesant_nip = '555-555-5555'
```

I get error

> value is too long for varchar(10).

This suggests that '-' characters were not removed before insert-update.

Why is my trigger not being executed?

```
CREATE FUNCTION normalize_nip() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- replace '' to NULL
    IF (NEW.interesant_nip LIKE '') THEN
        NEW.interesant_nip := NULL;
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

    -- remove '-' from string
    NEW.interesant_nip := REPLACE(NEW.interesant_nip, '-', '');

    RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;"

CREATE TRIGGER interesant_nip_normalize BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.interesant FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE normalize_nip()
```

Comment: @Lucas 'after' is too late, saved value will be too big for this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated or inserted value is always treated as type `varchar(10)` - before and after the trigger function. So, you cannot handle the value because the input type does not fit the value even if the trigger function converts it into a valid one.

It works if you have an unbounded text type. There you can see that the trigger is executed:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2a2f59584e59277da8a527f800dd4e17)

---

So, the only chance to handle this, is, to normalize it before inserting or updating:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=be90efdc17134e969ca97d882532eeec)

```
INSERT INTO interesant VALUES (normalize_nip('555-555-5555'));

UPDATE interesant SET interesant_nip = normalize_nip('555-555-5555')
```

Comment: It's very weird that size check is executed before `before` event. All databases work that way?

Comment: It's not the size, it is the **type**. Let's assume another example: You have an int column. And before inserting you always want to add +10. So the trigger takes the input and does the addition. But suddenly you are putting in a text value "abc". This wouldn't work because the trigger assumes an integer value. It would fail as well. That's exactly the same case because '555-555-5555' is a different type than varchar(10).